# Show multiple textfield based on dropdown's change value

Tags: javascript, php

I have four dropdown's value.

```
Job
Business
Study
Other
```

If Job is selected than company name and designation textbox should be visible.
If Business is selected than business field is visible
If Study is selected than class and college should be visible and for other just one text box should be visible.

I just know about if other field is selected than how to show it. Dont know what to do in this kind of prob.

Comment: My dear friend you forgot to post your code ..please paste it

Answer (score 0):

First, give all of them the same class ( i went with selection ), and then give all of the related text fields another specific class.

`<input class="selection Study" name="class />` and

`<input class="selection study" name="college">` and for company,

`<input class="selection Business" name="designation">`

In jquery, it'd be

```
$('.dropdown').on('change', function() {
    $('.selection').hide();
    var val = $(this).val();   

    $('.' + val).show();
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer jquery, which this would be easier in, but here is a pure Javascript solution:

```
//onclick on a select tag it runs a function
document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].onclick = function () {

    //it hides all the input tags. It finds the array of inputs first, change the numbers to change which input tags it hides.
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2].style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[3].style.display = 'none';

    //shows the input that has an id equal to the value of the select that was clicked.
    document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
}
```